# Static files don't load in django framework

Tags: django

django don't load static files, on the site when i use f12 i can see that /static/js/.., but styles not work

Template home-page.html

```
{% load static %}
```

piece of code and

```
 <!-- JQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app1/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app1/js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app1/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '../js/mdb.min.js' %}"></script>
  <!-- Initializations -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Animations initialization
    new WOW().init();
```

urls.py

```
from commercemag import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app1.urls', namespace='item-list')),
]


if settings.DEBUG:     
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

it's settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root')
```

idk what i should do, please help me

Answer (score 1):

add this in your code

```
import os

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Comment: added, but nothing

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in urls.py but this is only work when we posting any images from templates and stored in static files

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

also try this

comment your `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

Answer (score 0):

update settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

Comment: nothing(( idk what is it

Comment: In your settings.py Search for Templates and add static in DIRS

Comment: added, don't work

Comment: is your path is correct